# How to configure PagerDuty alerts in Splunk Cloud?

Tags: splunk, pagerduty

I've run into a few different issues with the PagerDuty integration in Splunk Cloud.

The documentation on PagerDuty's site is either outdated, not applicable to Splunk Cloud or else there's something wrong with the way my Splunk Cloud account is configured (could be a permissions issue): https://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/splunk-integration-guide/. I don't see an Alert Actions page in Splunk Cloud, I have a Searches, Reports and Alerts page though.

I've configured PD alerts in Splunk using the alert_logevent app but it's not clear if I should instead be using some other app. These alerts do fire when there are search hits but I'm seeing another issue (below). The alert_webhook app type seems like it might be appropriate but I was unable to get it to work correctly. I cannot create an alert type using the pagerduty_incident app. . . although I can set it as a Trigger Action (I guess this is how it's supposed to work, I don't find the UI to intuitive here).

When my alerts fire and create incidents in PagerDuty, I do not see a way to set the PagerDuty incident severity.

Also, the PD incidents include a link back to Splunk, which I believe should open the query with the search hits which generated the alert. However, the link brings me to a page with a Page Not Found! error. It contains a link to "more information about my request" which brings up a Splunk query with no hits. This query looks like "index=_internal, host=SOME_HOST_ON_SPLUNK_CLOUD, source=*web_service.log, log_level=ERROR, requestid=A_REQUEST_ID". It it not clear to me if this is a config issue, bug in Splunk Cloud or possibly even a permissions issue for my account.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also a Splunk Cloud + PagerDuty customer and ran into the same issue. The [PagerDuty App for Splunk](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3013/) seems to create all incidents as `Critical` but you can set different severities with event rules.

One way to do this is [dynamically](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/dynamic-notifications) is to rename your Splunk alerts with the desired severity level and then create a PagerDuty event rule for each level that looks for the keyword in the Summary. For example...

If the following condition is met:

`Summary contains "TEST"`

Then perform the following actions:

`Set severity = Info`

[screenshot of the example in the event rule edit screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpQBC.png)

It's a bit of pain to rename your existing alerts in Splunk but it works.

If your severity levels in Splunk are programmatically set like in Enterprise Security, then another method would be to modify the PagerDuty App for Splunk to send the `$alert.severity$` [custom alert action token](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.4/AdvancedDev/ModAlertsLog) as a custom detail in the webhook payload and use that as event rule condition instead of Summary... but that seems harder.